Does SpaceX have an intended site on Mars?
Elon Musk recently said that SpaceX intends to launch 5 supply missions to Mars in 2026, initiating a Mars base.
Is anything known about where the destination on Mars would be? Are there any obvious candidate sites?

The last I heard was when Musk said in the April 2024 update that it will be in a fairly deep area, so that starships can use airresistance longer to slow down a bit more

related (with helpful links): Has there ever been an attempt or serious consideration for spacecraft to land on Mars without an ablative-type heat shield? and What would the BFS' landing on Mars be like, if it is different from this animation? and Do exploration spacecraft enter Mars atmosphere against Mars rotation, or on the same direction?

and SpaceX and propulsive landing on Mars -- what just happened? (and why?) and possibly Are there any at least somewhat authoritative estimates of how long it will be before people will land on Mars and setting up camp?

SpaceX hasn't provided much information on the landing site for of the first Mars mission, so we have to rely on the few hints available so far. One of the main considerations for an early Mars mission is that the landing site should be close to the equator. This offers several benefits: more moderate temperatures, a speed boost for rockets due to Mars's rotation and increased sunlight for solar power.
Additionally, in his April 2024 update, Elon Musk mentioned that the first landing would likely be in a low-altitude area to allow Starship to benefit from increased air resistance, helping it to slow down more effectively. A lower-altitude site would also be slightly warmer.
According to Space.com, a recent paper about the first tree on Mars, found that the Hellas Planitia could be a promising starting location. Although the paper doesn’t focus on the first human landing site, Hellas Planitia meets key criteria for such a mission: it is low-lying and close to the equator. At 7,152 meters deep, Hellas Planitia is the lowest area on Mars, providing natural protection from radiation and temperature extremes, and it is not too far from the equator (around 45 degrees). Therefore, Hellas Planitia could be a strong contender for the first human landing site on Mars. However, we won't know until SpaceX confirms it.


Thank you! What do you mean "7,152 meters deep"? Deep relative to what?

@SteveBennett the 7152 meters is how low the Hellas Planitia is relative to where the ground would be it if there weren’t a crater. So in other words, relative to the Martian "Sea level"

@SteveBennett For more on that, see How were Mars' zero elevation datum defined? What are their shapes? and if you want to go further down the gravitational martian rabbithole, maybe Do Curiosity's reported measurements of Mars' surface gravity (~3.717 m/s^2) include centrifugal effects? and How much is the difference of gravity attraction between the highest and lowest point on Mars?

Ah, thanks. That's a deep crater!
